# Who are Rock Lee's, Tenten's and Hinata's parents?

Tags: naruto

Who are Rock Lee's, Tenten's and Hinata's parents?

In the show, they don't show a lot of parents. I used to think that Might Guy was Lee's father or a relative of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have any information about Rock Lee's and Tenten's parents. Neither in manga nor in anime of Naruto. Among the three, Tenten has the least past stories and background information.

As for Hinata, her father's name is [Hiashi Hyuga](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiashi_Hy%C5%ABga). The name of [Hinata's mother](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hinata_and_Hanabi%27s_Mother) didn't appear in manga or anime. Actually Hinata's mother never appeared in manga, only in anime, so I can't say it is canon.